# Mobile Safari localStorage and private mode error

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari

**Our test iphone has 'Do Not Track' OFF in Safari settings.**

However, when we try to write to localStorage we get this

```
> sessionStorage.setItem('s',3)
< Error: QuotaExceededError: DOM Exception 22
```

like it is in private mode(figured out after SO search).

What's the cause of this and how do i write to localStorage then?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out somebody accidentally turned private mode on.
Its a small button on the bottom left, when u are switching between the tabs

Nobody in the team has or had an iphone for a very long time :)